# Linux: create a file with the information of other file like row count, filename and char count

Tags: linux, unix

I am trying to create a file with the information of other file

I have:
myfile_yymmdd.txt (data = xyzagadsrscs)

I am Trying:

newfile.int (data to be like:  date|filename|rowcount|charcount)

```
      newfile_yymmdd.int          11/20/14|myfile_yymmdd.txt|1|12
```

This is what I have so far:

```
#wc myfile.txt >> newfile_yymmdd.int

#date `date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S` >> newfile_yymmdd.int

# printf "\n" >> myfile_yymmdd.txt

DELIMITER="~[~"
FILE_DATE=`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`
FILE_NAME=newfile.int
#ROW_COUNT=`wc -l < myfile_yymmdd.txt`
ROW_COUNT=`sed -n '=' myfile_yymmdd.txt | wc -l`
CHAR_COUNT=`wc -c < myfile_yymmdd.txt`
a=$FILE_DATE$DELIMITER$FILE_NAME$DELIMITER$ROW_COUNT$DELIMITER$CHAR_COUNT

echo $a > newfile.int (this will create the desired file)
echo $a
```

I am getting results but unable to copy the name of myfile with data stamp(myfile_yymmdd)
like :
     10/20/2014|myfile_|1|12

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Where in the script are you trying to copy something?

Comment: why `DELIMITER="~[~"` if desired output is separated by `|`? Why `date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S` if desired output is of the form `10/20/2014`? Why so much commented out code left? Why `sed -n "=" | wc -l` instead of `wc -l`?

Comment: @Mikyra: apologies. You are right.. any delimiter is fine i gave it as an example. myfile_yyyymmdd_hhmmss.txt to newfile_yyyymmdd_hhmmss.

Comment: @Mikyra: apologies. You are right.. any delimiter is fine i gave it as an example. ihave a file "myfile_yyyymmdd_hhmmss.txt" which contains 1 row and 12 chars in it, i want to create a file "newfile_yyyymmdd_hhmmss.int",  newfile data would be like "20141120_100459~[~myfile_yyyymmdd_hhmmss.txt~[~1~[~12"..

Comment: I can't really understand the question as you have written it but try using touch command to create the file then echo to it:

Something Like: 
touch $filename
echo $data > $filename